# Assign the output of a command to a Makefile variable does not work as expected

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to execute a command of a makefile and checks if there is any output to display. It works for some functions but not for others. For example, this command

```
isort:
    $(info ########################)
    $(info ### isort validation ###)
    $(info ########################)
    $(eval output=$(shell $(CONDA_ACTIVATE) $(ENV_NAME) && poetry run isort --profile black .))
    echo $(output)
ifeq ($(output),)
    $(info Ok)
else
    echo $(output)
endif
    echo ""
```

result in

```
########################
### isort validation ###
########################
Ok
Skipped 1 files
```

As you can see, the output is `Skipped 1 files` but seems to be evaluated as an empty string as `Ok` proves it. Even more strange (at least to me) is that `Ok` is actually displayed before the `output` which tells me that the `if` condition is evaluated before `output` variable is assigned.

Comment: The "hacky" way could be to check the condition in a bash way like `@if  [ -z "${output}" ]; then echo "ok"; else echo $(output); fi`

Comment: explanation of why what I did is not correct: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html

Answer (score 3):

In make, any line which is *not* indented with a TAB, is *not* part of the recipe.  Even if it "looks like" it is part of the recipe.  Recipes don't last until the first blank line or something like that.

So, the `ifeq` is not part of the recipe.  It's parsed by make when the makefile is being parsed.  The recipe itself is not expanded until after all the makefiles are completely parsed and make decides it wants to build that target.

You cannot use `ifeq` (any make conditional) to query values that are set as part of the recipe.  You'll have to use either shell functions or the make function `$(if ...)`, which can be embedded in a recipe.

In general it's a really bad idea to use either `$(eval ...)` or `$(shell ...)` inside a recipe.  It really leads to a lot of confusion about what exactly is going on and you will wander further and further down the rabbit hole.

If I were going to write your rule I would do it like this:

```
isort:
        @echo '########################'
        @echo '### isort validation ###'
        @echo '########################'
        output=$$($(CONDA_ACTIVATE) $(ENV_NAME) && poetry run isort --profile black .); \
        @echo "${output:-OK}"
        @echo
```

But really, I wouldn't bother trying to capture the output so I could print a separate value if it was empty.  It seems unnecessary to me so I would just run the command:

```
isort:
        @echo '########################'
        @echo '### isort validation ###'
        @echo '########################'
        $(CONDA_ACTIVATE) $(ENV_NAME) && poetry run isort --profile black .
        @echo Done.
        @echo
```

Comment: the issue with your second proposition is that `Done` is displayed before the output of the command which is confusing. That was also the goal of capturing the output into a variable

Comment: Why is the _Done_ be displayed before the command output?

Comment: There is no way that can be the case, if you use `echo` to show the "Done".  Are you using the commands I showed?  Or did you switch back to using `$(info ...)` to display output?